# how to check the range using only if statement

Tags: java

How can I write the code with a specific requirement having the range between `frontR` and `frontL` that must be between `1-3`?

Code:

```
System.out.println("Input right front pressure: ");
frontR = keyboard.nextInt();

if (frontR >= 32 && frontR <= 42) {
    inflation = "good";
}
else{
        warning = "Warning: pressure is out of range";
        inflation = "BAD";
}

System.out.println("Input left front pressure: ");
frontL = keyboard.nextInt();

if (frontL >= 32 && frontL <= 42) {
    inflation = "good";
}
else {
    warning = "Warning: pressure is out of range";
    inflation = "BAD";
}
```

Comment: Suppose you had a function which returned the difference between two numbers. Could you write it then?

Comment: Hello Rio and welcome to StackOverflow. I am afraid you question won't get any proper answers soon, because it is not actually a question. Better would be if you were to tell us your problems, your ideas and show us your solution. Don't worry if works or not.

Comment: HINT: `Math.abs(frontL - frontR)` might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check the difference between two numbers, you need to subtract them. The result may be negative if the first number is smaller than the second, so you may want to use `Math.abs()` which will make it positive again. Then you have a positive number that you can check for being between 1 and 3:

```
int difference = Math.abs(frontL - frontR);

if (difference >= 1 && difference <= 3) {
    inflation = "good";
}
else {
    warning = "Warning: difference between pressure left and right detected";
    inflation = "BAD";
}
```